# Tomcat stop after failed deployment?

Tags: tomcat7

I would like to stop Tomcat when a war deployment fails. Is there some hook or listener which could be used for that?

I know, normally one would not make the container stop when a deployment fails. In my case I would like to implement a [Fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) error model with Tomcat since there is currently no chance to replace the WAR with a fat jar with an embedded Servlet engine (e.g., Spring-Boot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mean time I have implemented a Tomcat LifecycleListener which shuts down TC when a deployment fails: https://github.com/ascheman/tomcat-lifecyclelistener

Thanks to Thomas Meyer who gave some hints on Twitter: https://twitter.com/thomasmey/status/752971635825729537.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot provides shutdown hook. SOF has similar query as below

[Spring Boot shutdown hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678208/spring-boot-shutdown-hook)

This can give and idea to implement your app Fail Fast behavior with hook.

Comment: It was a legacy (third party commercial) application deployed which failed.