# Properly terminate Spring Boot and Tomcat if initialization of AppContext fails

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

When I start Spring Boot application on embedded Tomcat and something fails during startup (for instance there is no connection to DB or Liquibase update fails or circular dependency found, etc), Tomcat continues listening on 8080 port.

If I send HTTP request to some endpoint, an application returns 404 NOT FOUND.

1. Is this expected behavior (should Tomcat continue listening)?
2. How to stop Spring Boot and Tomcat when initialization of the application context fails?

Here EXAMPLE of the log:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.test.Application.main(Application.java:33)
```

After this exception Tomcat still available on the specified port.

**UPD**

application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.default=production
spring.application.name=test

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test123
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

liquibase.change-log=classpath:/liquibase/changelog.xml
```

dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <spring.boot.version>1.5.9.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>

    <liquibase.version>3.5.3</liquibase.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
    <hsqldb.version>2.4.0</hsqldb.version>

    <powermock.version>1.7.3</powermock.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.14.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cache</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**UPD 2**

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.test")
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public Application() {
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your config file & pom.xml

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond done

Comment: Also please share the `Application.java`

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond done. Nothing special in Application.java

Comment: Hi add 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat' and plugin 'spring-boot-maven-plugin' to dependencies. Override configure method in Application class  with return "return application.sources(Application.class);" this sould fix config initialization. Is there any reason why you excluding tomcat-annotations-api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be 2 scenarios in this.

### Scenario 1

Application is up and running, the App Context is created and then some runtime exception occurs in the server and you want to do a graceful shutdown. In this scenario, you can use a utility like [Spring boot Graceful shutdown](https://github.com/corentin59/spring-boot-graceful-shutdown).

[image: Ref: https://github.com/corentin59/spring-boot-graceful-shutdown]

### Scenario 2

This is the scenario which occurs when Spring Boot is unable to create the Application context itself. Your scenario falls into this category. When application boots up, it tries to wire up the configurations from the application.properties and if there are any issues, the application context itself would not be created.

Hence in this scenario, you cannot opt for a graceful shutdown as you don't have an instance of Application context. In such cases, you can catch the exception, choose appropriate logging and do a system exit manually.

```java
try{
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args).close();;
}
catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Going to exit");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

After this, Tomcat instance will not be running and port would be available to use.

Comment: Looks like try/catch from the second scenario fixes the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Surprisingly hard to find this information out. I also fell in to the second case with a BeanCreationException and my app just kept running. I thought it should fail and stop by default, maybe there is still a problem there somewhere, but this solution did help me to at least stop the app.